# Recursive function: Keep original argument

Tags: function, python-2.7, recursion, binary-tree

I have implemented a sorting function for a treap:

```
def treesort(node, root):
    if node is None:
        return

    # Left child has higher priority
    if node.left != None and node.left.priority > node.priority:
        node = treerotateright(node)
        treesort(root, root)

    # Right child has higher priority
    if node.right != None and node.right.priority > node.priority:
        node = treerotateleft(node)
        treesort(root, root)

    treesort(node.left, root)
    treesort(node.right, root)
```

Basically you navigate recursively through your treap and if one of the children has a higher
priority you rotate the higher priority up. *treesort()* will be called after a new node has been inserted. So there is only one node unsorted and it should be rotated as long as the treap is unsorted.
Instead of an outer loop calling *treesort()* repeatedly until the treap is sorted, I had the idea of adding another 'recursion-layer?' if an unsorted node is detected. 
I would like *treesort()* to be called with the original node==root it was called with.

My problem is that I don't know any other way to save the root other than adding another argument which is just parsed through.

**Original intended use:** *treesort(root)*
**Now:** *treesort(root, root)*

I know I could just write another function calling this one that had only one argument. I am just curious if there is another more elegant way like (it doesn't work):

```
def treesort(node, root=node):
...
```

Comment: How about an overloaded function?  Have one version that takes only the first argument and calls the second version with that argument twice?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use some kind of sentinel default value, often `None`:

```
def treesort(node, root=None):
    if root is None:
        root = node
    ...
```